# Hoffman and Kunze, linear algebra Chapter 2 sec 2.3 exercise 11

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ with complex entries which satisfy $A_{11}+A_{22}=0.$

(a) Show that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R.}$ (This was easy.)

(b) Find a basis for this vector space.

Since the matrix should be of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a+ib & p+iq\\c+id&-a-ib\end{bmatrix}a,b,c,d,p,q\in \mathbb{R.}$ I think $\{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}i & 0\\0&-i\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\i&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & i\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\}$ would do as a basis.

(c) Let $W$ be the set of all matrices $A$ in $V$ such that $A_{21}=-\overline{A_{12}}.$ Prove that $W$ is a subspace of $V$ and find a basis for $W.$

Since the matrix should be of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a+ib & p+iq\\-p+iq&-a-ib\end{bmatrix}a,b,p,q\in \mathbb{R.}$ I think the basis would be $\{\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}i & 0\\0&-i\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0 & i\\i&0\end{bmatrix}\}$.

> I want to know if the the basis vectors are correct. Are there any redundant ones or vectors which I am missing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to tell at least whether the elements of that set you call basis are linearly independent over the reals $\;\Bbb R\;$ ...and they are.

Now take any element $\;A\in V\;$ , so that you can write

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&\!-a\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;a,b,c\in\Bbb C$$

Observe that you can write $\;A\;$ as a linear combination of the set you give, so this is *in fact* a basis.

**Another way** Using the above general form for an element $\;A\in V\;$ , it is clear that $\;a,b,c\;$ can be anything in $\;\Bbb C\;$ , and this gives us a space of *real* dimension $\;2\cdot3=6\;$ , so your six elements are a basis indeed.

Can you also see now why for the other part you got a basis as well?

Comment: Oh thank you for "Another way"!!

Comment: No, in any element of V a,b and c are **complex numbers** not real numbers as you pointed out.

Comment: @bedbad Yes...that was merely a typo, as it is clear from what follows 3 lines below. Corrected, and thanks.

Comment: Now, after you edited you see that V  with 3some basis of a, b, c is **not** a vector space over R (which was requested), but the vector space over C

Comment: It's not merely a typo, that the whole point of this exercise, unfortunately. You showed it for C, not for R

Comment: In R you would get whole bunch of different parameters - you eliminate "complexity" from the view

Comment: You need to find the minimal dimensionality of such representation. I.e R^6 (it will be > R^3, clearly) and you need to prove it by showing that this basis is independent

Comment: This is **wrong**. The fact that a vector space has dimensionality N and you found N vectors it doesn't make them basis. You need to **prove** that the are Linearly Independent!

Comment: @bedbad Either you're very wrong, imo, or you're talking of something I've no idea whatsover: **any** complex vector space of dimension $\;n\;$ can *pretty naturally and simply* be seen as a **real** vector space of dimension $\;2n\;$ , thus: if the $\;\dim_{\Bbb C}V=3\;$ , then clearly $\;\dim_{\Bbb R}V=6\;$ , which is what I wrote

Comment: @bedbad About your last comment: nobody said that *any* set of $\;n\;$ vectors in a $\;n\,-$ dimensional space is automatically a basis. You either need linear indep. or else that it is a generating set. **This is** what is written above...

Comment: You need to explicitly that this answer(which is correct) is a generating set - by explitcy turning it into 6x6 identity matrix

Comment: @bedbad I need nothing. Perhaps the OP does, but it is enough to show that it is a generating linearly independent set, which is what my answer hints at...and which is pretty simple to show, btw.